# UK fixed penalty notice for EU resident

Tags: united-kingdom, fines

If an EU citizen (and EU resident) travels to the UK and receives an FPN ([Fixed Penalty Notice](https://www.gov.uk/pay-challenge-fine-environmental-offence)) in the UK for littering, can the UK still enforce the fine? Would the UK authorities need something more than the ID of the person to enforce payment?

Is an FPN, from a legal perspective, like a traffic violation? Is enforcement common?

Comment: See also: https://law.stackexchange.com/q/52790/10334

Answer (score -1):

### Yes, the fine can be enforced

The UK is unlikely to pursue the perpetrators a foreign jurisdiction to collect but they can.

Comment: There is a reasonable chance that the perpetrator will be flagged when they try to enter the U.K. again and have the choice of paying on the spot or be refused entry. Usually happens for unpaid hospital bills.

Comment: Thus answer is missing explanation of the mechanism and how.

Comment: Germany will from time to time ask for example US citizens who are likely falsely accused of traffic crimes. Car exceeds the speed limit in Germany. Owner claims, "I wasn't driving, it was my friend visiting from the USA". Suddenly _lots_ of people use the excuse. German police eventually asks some of the accused people, and sometimes they don't exist, sometimes they were never in Germany, sometimes they definitely didn't drive the car in question - and then things get very expensive for the German car owner. AFAIK they don't pursue the accused people at all.

Comment: @JosephCorrectEnglishPronouns That's because the mechanism isn't part of the law. As the answer says, pursuit is unlikely. But it's legally possible.

Comment: @gnasher729 a former judge in NSW was jailed for falsely making a statutory declaration that an American was driving his car. Turns out she was dead at the time.